# College Student Loan Forgiveness Law

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-federal-government

Does the Biden $10,000 forgiveness plan for students require Congressional approval? Why or why not? Do certain laws have Congress exemption?

[Student Loan Forgiveness](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2022/08/23/biden-near-decision-10-000-student-loan-cancellation/7868363001/)

Comment: The link is a bad link and it is important to know the details of the proposal (which may not be fully available yet) to evaluate it.

Comment: @ohwilleke the link just had a double https: in it, I've corrected it.

Comment: why is this voted down? I am trying to learn @Eugene

Comment: @mattsmith5 I didn't vote you down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's pre-authorized by Congress.

He is (ab?)using the 2003 HEROES act, that was passed to help military families during the War on Terror. It has a provision that the Secretary of Education can "waive or modify **any** statutory or regulatory provision applicable to the federal student loan program" **during an emergency**. The Covid-19 public health emergency has been extended multiple times and is still officially in effect. QED

Direct justification from the administration:

> You have asked whether the HEROES Act authorizes the Secretary to
> address the financial hardship arising out of the COVID -19 pandemic
> by reducing or canceling the principal balances of student loans for a
> broad class of borrowers. We conclude that the Act grants that
> authority. The plain text of the HEROES Act authorizes the Secretary
> to “waive or modify any statutory or regulatory provision applicable
> to” the federal student loan program, 20 U.S.C. § 1098bb(a)(1)
> (emphasis added), an authority that encompasses provisions applicable
> to the repayment of the principal balances of loans, provided certain
> conditions are met. We conclude that targeting relief towards those
> individuals who suffered financial hardship because of COVID -19 and
> who otherwise satisfy the requirements of the Act accords with the
> Act’s requirement that the waiver or modification “be necessary to
> ensure that” student loan recipients who are “affected” by a national
> emergency “are not placed in a worse position financially” with
> respect to their loans as a result.

Source: https://townhall.com/tipsheet/madelineleesman/2022/08/26/biden-admin-defends-using-post-9-11-law-on-student-debt-forgiveness-n2612306